# wierd softbody/collision effects working then not working without changing anything (blender 2.79)

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]Wondering if anyone might have any insight into this.

For simplicity, I have two UV spheres.

I then translate one by 2 units. I create a simple keyframe animation so the two spheres will colide (0,0,0).

On the stationary sphere, I first add a subdivision modifier (2,2), apply it, smooth it, then make it a softbody in the physics tab.

On the moving sphere, I add a subdivision modifier (2,2), then add the collision in the physics tab.

Now. I animate it.

"Sometimes" blender will see it collide. And "sometimes" it won't.

I don't change a single thing. I'll play it/animate it. It works. I go back to frame 0, it stops working.

ANY idea? Driving me nuts.

It also seems creating particle systems from a UV sphere go all wacky too. Instead of 'gradually' having particles come out from the sphere, they will magically translate by 30% (as opposed to a gradual 1% over an animatinon), and look totally wacky. Maybe that's related I don't know.

ANY ideas what is going on?

This picture is from a project I am working on. The entire 'soft body' seems to be totally whacked out. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Please keep only one question per post, ask as many as necessary. Some screenshots might also help.

Comment: Okay, on the first question. It's wierd (taken me 12 hours today, and maybe kind of figuring this out) - if I 'manually' step through EACH and EVERY single keyframe (timeconsuming) - it seems to render the animation properly (and also makes the .blend file larger if I save it). BUT - if I go back/forth on the keyframe, then try and render the animation, it either does wierd/whacky transformations, or 'forgets' about certain physics. Any idea what is going on/happening, and/or how to fix it?

Comment: posted a picture. this is an example of the 'whacky' dynamics that are going on.